# Scala fs2: what fromFreeC and Algebra do?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, fs2

When I go into the implementation of fs2 stream operations I often see `fromFreeC` and `Algebra` used there.

**What exactly `fromFreeC` and `Algebra` do? Why and when one needs them?**

Here is an example, an fs2 stream operation `eval` which evaluates effects and returns an effectful stream.

```
def eval[F[_], O](fo: F[O]): Stream[F, O] =
   fromFreeC(Algebra.eval(fo).flatMap(Algebra.output1))
```

Comment: Since you are in the source code, you will see that at the end a **Stream** just a _type alias_ of a **Free** of values. A **Free** is a **Monad** which allows infinite data recursion. Also, as **IO** it is also an _ADT_ to ensure lazyness that is the **Algebra**. So at then end a **Stream** is just a datastructure that represents some computations which is interpreted in runtime to evaluate all the side effects and produces the real values. - However as an user, you shouldn't really care about that, since that is an implementation detail. - Disclaimer: I am **NOT** an `fs2` contributor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I guess I need to learn more FP because it does not quite make sense to me.

Comment: Yeah, neither does for me, and probably I have a couple of errors in my explanation. It is true that you may need to study more to understand the implementation of **Stream**, but you do not need too much to understand how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In the source code for version `2.1.0`, classes `Pull`, `Stream`, and `FreeC` were defined as follows:

```
class FreeC[F[_], +O, +R]
class Pull[+F[_], +O, +R](free: FreeC[Nothing, O, R]) 
class Stream[+F[_], +O](free: FreeC[Nothing, O, Unit])
```

The key problem is that `Stream` and `Pull` were *covariant* on the `F[_]` parameter, whereas `FreeC` is invariant. As a consequence, you cannot apply the `F` parameter of `Stream` or `Pull` directly to the `FreeC` type of the wrapped value. To bridge that, we used `Nothing` as argument for `FreeC` in those `free` fields, and apply use `asInstanceOf` conversions between a `FreeC[Nothing, O, Unit]` to a `FreeC[F O, Unit]`, and back again.

However, [in this Pull Request](https://github.com/typelevel/fs2/pull/1730) we made the class `FreeC` *covariant* on `F[_]`, just like `Stream` and `Pull`, so we could just define:

```
class FreeC[+F[_], +O, +R]
class Pull[+F[_], +O, +R] (free: FreeC[F, O, R])
class Stream[+F[_], +O] (free: FreeC[F O, Unit])
```

Thus, the `fromFreeC` function was dropped. This was included in release `2.2.0`.

---

The use of `Nothing` makes use of a Scala-2 type system feature: both `Any` and `Nothing` are polykinded types, so they can be applied as arguments for type parameters of the form `A`, `F[_]`, `A[_[_]]`, etc.